# Java, Cannot find symbol error?

Tags: java, math

I am trying to compute the total price given the unit price, 17, and the number of items, 20.

```
public class hw1_task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = units * price;
        int units = 20;
        int price =  17;
        System.out.printf("The total is: %d", total);
    }    
}
```

What is wrong with the program? I keep getting an error about not being able to find the symbols. I am very new to java, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move units and price above total like this:

```
int price =  17;
int units = 20;
int total = units * price;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variable before the declaration. These lines

```
int units = 20;
int price =  17;
```

should be written first and

```
int total = units * price;
```

after that.
So the correct lines will be:

```
int units = 20;
int price =  17;
int total = units * price;
```

Answer (score 2):

Before using the variable you need to declare it.

Here in your program, you used "units" and "price" variable before it is declared, so you are getting error saying "cannot find the symbol".

and to print the value use System.out.println()

```
public class hw1_task3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int units = 20;  //Variable declaration and initialization
        int price =  17;  //Variable declaration and initialization
        int total = units * price;
        System.out.println("The total is: "+total);
    }    
}
```